# Gold tag badge not awarded, despite congratulations banner

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges

I get this on my user page:

[image]

Why do I get shown this, when I don't actually own the badge? When I click "track the next one", it shows my progress towards python again:

[image]

Surely it's a bug to, within the same UI component, tell me that I both have and haven't received the badge?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that this one can actually be revoked if the cumulative post score drops below the threshold.  There was one user who saw two different notifications for the "same" tag badge notification (his was bronze).

Comment: See [Badge apparently awarded, but not showing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253638/badge-apparently-awarded-but-not-showing) - Tag badges are only awarded once a day at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: @animuson: how come after clicking track the next one, it thinks my requirements are insufficient then? (see my updated images)

Comment: That part is already on the [todo list for fixes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253516) (see comments).

Comment: Yep, this is an exact duplicate of that answer